# SwiftUI equivalent to UIKit UITextField's UITextContentType

Tags: swiftui

Does SwiftUI provide an equivalent modifier to UIKit `UITextContentType` for `TextField` and `SecureField`

UIKit allows you to specify the content type of a `UITextField` e.g `.oneTimeCode` or `.email` to allow the field to work with the system autofill. Is there an equivalent view modifier for SwiftUI.

Im NOT looking for solutions with `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: No, you you can make validators or use formatters but nothing built in. There are tools out there like [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) that might let you set it. I've never tried it but see in mentioned here quite a bit.

Comment: `.textContentType(.emailAddress)` and `.keyboardType(.emailAddress)` modifiers for TextField should work, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @CenkBilgen no not missing anything. Can you create an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SecureField` for passwords. You can also set `.textContentType` as you wish.

```
            SecureField("Password", text: .constant("password"))
                .textContentType(.password)
```